# Tensorflow "matching" two tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to implement a custom loss function that compares y_actual with y_prediction, so that the loss function would count how many elements match in the tensors at a given position, and returns that number as the loss. I tried accessing the elements, and calculating it manually, but I guess that would need to read the values from GPU to CPU at each iteration and would be catastrophically slow.
What I'd like is

```
y_actual = [[1,2],[3,4]]
y_prediction = [[1,0],[3,4]]
# since 3 elems match in their corresponding positions, and 1 doesn't
loss = 3 (or better, 1-3/4)
```

I'm not well-versed in machine learning or in Tensorflow, so quite lost in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tensorflow 2.0 you can simply do a:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_actual = [[1,2],[3,4]]
y_prediction = [[1,0],[3,4]]

print(tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.equal(y_actual,y_prediction)))
```

**The OUTPUT will be :**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=3>
```

In case you are looking to get the exact number just do a :

```
print(tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.equal(y_actual,y_prediction)).numpy())
```

Comment: Thanks! It has no gradient to be a loss function, but I guess that's another issue.